# Distinguishing $0/1$ unimodular or singular matrices having $\mathsf{Permanent}\in\{0,1\}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-fields, multilinear-algebra, permanent

Let $\mathcal T_n=\{M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}:\mathsf{Per}(M)=\mathsf{Det}(M)\wedge\mathsf{Det}(M)\in\{0,1\}\}$ (restricted set unimodular or singular having permanent and determinant identical).

$\DeclareMathOperator\Det{Det}\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$Denote by $\Det_{m,\mathcal I,\mathcal J}(A)$ the subdeterminant of the $m\times m$ block indexed by $\mathcal I$ and $\mathcal J$ where $\abs{\mathcal I}=\abs{\mathcal J}=m$ of a matrix $A\in\mathcal T_n$ but entries considered in $\mathbb F_2$ where $m\leq n$ holds.

The usual determinant formula utilizing $\Det_{m,\mathcal I,\mathcal J}(A)$ has $n!$ terms at $m=1$.  If $m=1$ every $1×1$ subdeterminant is the entry of the matrix and so $\Det(A)$ has $n!$ terms.

Trivially $\Det(A)$ is a $\Det_{m,\mathcal I,\mathcal J}(A)$ formula having $1$ term at $m=n$. If $m=n$ every $n×n$ subdeterminant is $\Det(A)$ itself.

Let the number of $\Det_{m,\mathcal I,\mathcal J}(A)$ involved in a product for constructing terms be referred to as the $m$-degree of the formula and denote it by $d_m$. So a term is a product $\prod_{i=1}^r\Det_{m_i,\mathcal I_i,\mathcal J_i}(A)$ and $m$-degree is $r$ which if $m_i=1$ is the monomial degree.

> 1. Is there a relation between number of terms in the expression of $\Det(A)$ in terms of $\Det_{m,\mathcal I,\mathcal J}(A)$, $d_m$ and $m$?

> 2. Is the number of terms bound by $O\bigl(4^{a}n^{\frac{2^a}{a}}\bigr)$ terms at $m\geq n^{1/a}$ or at least $m\geq\frac n{2^a}$ if $md_m=\Omega(n)$ at any fixed $a\geq2$ (not unreasonable since at $a=1$ number of terms is $1$ and at a fixed $a>1$ number of terms is sublinear to quadratic)?

Is 2. correct at least if $A\in\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ since the parity of the number of terms is important? Perhaps number of terms is $O\big(4^{a}n^{\frac{2^a}{a}}\big)$. It agrees to Ryser's formula for $\Det(A)\bmod 2$ at $a=\log n$ without encoding https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RyserFormula.html.

---

Special situation where $\mathsf{determinant}(A)=\mathsf{permanent}(A)\in\{0,1\}$ is in $\mathsf{C}_{=}\mathsf{L}$, $\mathsf{NL}$, $\oplus\mathsf{L}$, $\mathsf{UL}$ and $\mathsf{monotoneAC}^1$ and is reducible to a $\mathsf{monotone}$ circuit but is not known to be in $\mathsf{L}$. If the circuit is also a tree (fan-out of gates is $1$) it is in $\mathsf{NC}^1$ or else it is open if the problem should be in $\mathsf{NC}^1$ (I think it is in $\mathsf{NC}^1$). $O(4^an^{\frac{2^a}a})$ number of terms places it in $\mathsf{NC}^1$. It is a matter of distinguishing unimodularity and singularity of $0/1$ matrices in $\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$.

---

I think the problem of placing in $\mathsf{NC}^1$ is hopeless. It think the broader picture is too big for the pigeonhole viewpoint of posted problem. I think any $\mathsf{NC}^1$ algorithm answers several seemingly unrelated problems.

Comment: Please be gentle with the reader and explain what you are talking about. Lines 3 and 4 of the post are not clear. Do you mean some iterated Laplace expansion where if $n=pm$ the big determinant is given by degree $p$ polynomial in the $m\times m$ minors?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam If $m=1$ every $1\times1$ subdeterminant is the entry of the matrix and so $Det(A)$ has $n!$ terms. If $m=n$ every $n\times n$ subdeterminant is $Det(A)$ itself. So a term is a product of $Det_{m,\mathcal I,\mathcal J}(A)$ and I am saying $m$-degree is $r$ in $\prod_{i=1}^rDet_{m_i,\mathcal I_i,\mathcal J_i}(A)$.

Comment: I think the problem may not be in $\mathsf{NC}^1$ unconditionally and hence we are missing the formulation sought in the literature.